# How to change radfilter filter container id programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using `radfilter` control to filter the data of `radgrid`.

```
<telerik:RadFilter 
    runat="server" 
    ID="RadFilter1" 
    FilterContainerID="RadGrid1" 
    ShowApplyButton="true" 
    Skin="Office2007" 
    ApplyButtonText="Apply Filter">
</telerik:RadFilter>
```

I want to change the `FilterContainerID` property programatically based on tab selection for filter the data of `radgrid`, but when I change the value of this property it is giving column names of old `radgrid` only.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how the RadGrid works but maybe this page is helpful to you http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/filter-grid-filtering.html.

> "Note that the filter expressions produced by the built-in filtering mechanism of RadGrid and those created by RadFilter are independent from each other"

Make sure that any filters that are held with the RadGrid and the RadFilter are cleared first, and then reset to the desired filter.

Also this may not be possible

> The filter expressions generated by the RadFilter control will depend on the data type of the source grid fields, thus making them protected from type conflicts and syntax errors.

The RadFilter control may function so that by changing the filter source, any potential typecasting errors or syntax errors won't occur.

Why not just create another filter for the other grids?

Comment: Ya, if there is no any other possibility then i will create another filter, because in my page 10 grids are there, in that only one grid is visible at a particular time, so that every time i need to hide the filter, thank you,

Comment: Have you poked around Telerik's forums to see if anyone has had a similar problem? They tend to be really slow with repsonses though :\

Comment: may be no one has this type of problem,